# ¿Cómo retornar valores de una función asíncrona que se ejecuta en un hilo?

Tags: python-3.x, hilos, websocket, asyncio

Soy nuevo usando funciones asíncronas e hilos y estoy tratando de retornar una serie de valores obtenidos de un Websocket para pasarlos a otro hilo donde se está ejecutando código síncrono. A continuación les muestro el código:

```
"""
Este código está diseñado para correr un loop asíncrono 
con asyncio en un hilo separado. Esto permite mezclar 
un código síncrono con uno asíncrono. 
"""
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
import websockets
from typing import Tuple, List, Iterable
import json
import time

URLS = [
    "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/xrpusdt@kline_1m",
    "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m",
]

def start_background_loop(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

async def SuscripcionIndividual(url: str):
    """Se crea una suscripcion individual a cada WebSocket"""
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        data = await websocket.recv()
        data = json.loads(data)

        print('\n', data)
           
        return data

async def Suscripciones(URLS: Iterable[str]):
    """Se suscriben todos los tickets de concurrente y se combinan todos
        en una sola corrutina."""
    while True:
        tareas = [asyncio.create_task(SuscripcionIndividual(url)) for url in URLS]
        
        # Se corren todas las tareas en paralelo 
        await asyncio.gather(*tareas)
        #return tareas

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    t = Thread(target=start_background_loop, args=(loop,), daemon=True)
    t.start()

    tareas = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(Suscripciones(URLS), loop)
    for i in tareas.result():
        print(f"{i}")

    #return tareas

def function():
        for i in range(100):
            print("Esto esta fuera de ejecución asíncrona ", i)
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    main()
    T2 = Thread(target=function,)
    T2.start()
```

Intente poner simplemente  `return`  al código asíncrono, pero al hacer, esto el bucle asíncrono solo se ejecuta una sola vez y no de forma continua como esperaría. ¿Es posible retornar valores de una función asíncrona?

Comment: Asyncio es una alternativa a threads y multiprocessing. ¿Para qué usar ambas cuando cualquier por separado puede?